# How to make function work with no parameters?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, parameters, definition

For example, if I want to have an input of a string like 'duck', and I need the function to spell out:

> d
>   u
>   c
>   k

but with no parameters--how do I do this?

```
def spell():
    '''Returns every character in a word or phrase'''
    print(input('Enter a word: '))
    for n in range(len(n)):
        print(n)
```

I was trying to make the above code work, but I had trouble because everything I tried prompted an error message that had to do with variables being undefined. How should I change my code?

Comment: `for n in range(len(raw_input('Enter a word: ')))`

Comment: @zero Adding the python-3.x tag was good, but you didn't need to add the "I'm currently using Python 3" line. The tag itself is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Another method using `str.join` -

```
def spell():
    '''Returns every character in a word or phrase'''
    print('\n'.join(input('Enter a word: ')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You were doing a few things wrong.

```
def spell():
    '''Returns every character in a word or phrase'''
    word = raw_input('Enter a word: ')
    for i in word:
        print(i)
```

If you're using Python3, you will have to change `raw_input` to `input`, as `input` does not exist in Python3 and works like `raw_input`.

Comment: How do you know it's Python 3? :)

Comment: Actually "but I had trouble because everything I tried prompted an error message that had to do with variables being undefined" reminds me of the error that you get when using `input` without quoting your strings in Python2 ;)

Comment: @rofls yeah you'll get a Name Error in 2 with that `input` which is very similar to the error OP is describing.

Comment: Yeah. OP does mentions an error, but i think its more like `n` is undefined. hard to say until OP comes back

Comment: If OP has quoted strings, then 2 will raise an UnboundLocalError at `for n in range(len(n))`, variable (n) referenced before assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
for n in range(len(n))
```

The problem specifically is that, at this point `n` has not been assigned, so while it is valid as an *iterator* (`for n`) it's failing at the `len(n)` part of the statement.

The resolution will be to first make sure you're assigning something *to* this variable, or, use your iterator over a valid object, like:

```
def spell():
    '''Returns every character in a word or phrase'''
    n = input('Enter a word: ')   # assign the input to 'n' 
    for n in range(len(n)):
        print(n)
```

(I would probably use different variable names, as using the same name for your iterator and your input is potentially confusing)

Or you could do:

```
def spell():
    print [n for n in range(len(input('Enter a word: ')))]
    """
    *for python 2.x:
       print [n for n in range(len(raw_input('Enter a word: ')))]
    *to return a list of the letters, do:
       return [n for n in range(len(raw_input('Enter a word: ')))]
    """
```

Comment: @JavierBuzzi how can you tell OP is using python 3?

Comment: he/she used `input()` instead of `raw_input()` and `print()` instead of `print 'stuff here'`

Comment: Actually, @DavidZemens, `raw_input` becomes `input` in Python3, I believe :)

Comment: @JavierBuzzi both `input` **and** `print('stuff')` are valid in python 2, though, so you're making an assumption about the OP's code and telling me that my code won't run based on that assumption. It is probably better to let OP clarify such things...

Comment: @SharonDwilifK has the best answer ive seen

Comment: @DavidZemens if he/she is asking how to make an input work and break it down i think its safe to assume they didnt add `from __future__ import print_function` and `from builtins import input` to make it all work..

Comment: I'm running this in 2.7 from a command prompt, with no import statements... what am I doing wrong then, if I should have to be importing these functions?  http://imgur.com/YGGf1OL @JavierBuzzi

Comment: The `print()` will work on the latest 2.7.10, the `input()` will not. You need to import it

Comment: I didn't import it, so, there's that... see for yourself: http://imgur.com/YGGf1OL

Comment: Yeah. issue is when you press enter http://imgur.com/a/cQbjU look. top one is 2.7 bottom one is 3

Comment: @JavierBuzzi that error happens because you didn't put quotes around your input string, it has nothing to do with needing to import the `input` function.